# how to set value in text_field and store these value into database table in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

These things i have all ready done, but at that time the value of text_field is not insert into database table, reaming value insert successfully but one value is not inserted.

I can understand where am i wrong and what is missing...

**_employee_details.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(:employee_details, :url => {:controller => 'hr', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :employee_id, { :value=> "123548", :disabled=>true , :required => true, placeholder: 'E12345678', class: 'form-control' } %>
<% end %>
```

**hr_controller.rb**

```
class HrController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.new
    end

    def create
        @employees = EmployeeDetail.new(employee_params)
        if @employees.save
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        else
            redirect_to :action => 'internal_employee_page'
        end
    end

    private

        def employee_params
             params.require(:employee_details).permit(:offer_letter_id, :employee_id, :bank_ac, :bank_ifsc, :spouse_name, :gender, :work_end_date)
        end     
end
```

All value is successfully insert into employee_details table accept **employee_id**

**employee_details.rb** this is my modal

```
class EmployeeDetail < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :user
    validates :offer_letter_id, presence: true 
end
```

**I have already try this but this is not working**

1. 

Comment: change `:disabled=>true` to `readonly`

Comment: `disabled` values will not pass through the `params`, but `readonly` values will

Comment: thanks you so much  Sravan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disabled input will not submit data.**

**Instead of disabled Use the readonly attribute:**

`<%= f.text_field :employee_id, { :value=> "123548", :readonly => true , :required => true, placeholder: 'E12345678', class: 'form-control' } %>`

```
<%= form_for(:employee_details, :url => {:controller => 'hr', :action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
       <%= f.text_field :employee_id, { :value=> "123548", :readonly => true , :required => true, placeholder: 'E12345678', class: 'form-control' } %>
<% end %>
```

[Here is the documentation of it](http://blog.netgloo.com/2014/05/31/disabling-an-input-field-in-a-form-and-sending-data/)